# What is wrong with this simple Java code?

Tags: java

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Object i = Integer.valueof(42);
        System.out.println(i);
     }
}
```

I am geeting the following error after compiling and executing the aforementioned code on the website http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php :

Compiling the source code....
$javac HelloWorld.java 2>&1

```
HelloWorld.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Object i = Integer.valueof(42);
                          ^
  symbol:   method valueof(int)
  location: class Integer
1 error
```

Comment: The `o` is capitalized, as in `Integer.valueOf`.

Comment: Use an IDE! like <http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `o` is capitalized you need to do `Integer.valueOf(42)` not `Integer.valueof(42)`

This form of spelling out multiple words without spaces and using capital letters to show the beginning of a word instead is called [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) and is the convention in Java